# Stellar Java Sdk key validation?

Tags: java-sdk, keypair, key, seed

In JavaScript SDK we have method `isValidEd25519PublicKey` for Stellar address validation. But in Java SDK there is no such method.

How can I validate Stellar address with Java SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StrKey.decodeStellarAccountId()` wrapped with a try-catch block. If the expression throws an exception, the account id is invalid.